# default a:hover overriding ones with classes ie6

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a default a:hover style as follows:

```
a:hover { color: black; font-size: 8pt }
```

However when trying to apply a class such as:

```
a.myclass:link { font-size: 14px } 
a.myclass:hover { color: red }
```

without the font-size, then it changes font-size back to 8pt.
Now this seems like how it should work however it doesn't happen in ie7, firefox, chrome. (It does work in IE6)

**Update:** In firebug it actually shows font-size on a:hover has been overridden, but by what i don't know.

Any one have any ideas?

Comment: It should show you in firebug what's overriding it (it'll be somewhere higher in the Style section)

Comment: I suppose its not overriding it in IE6 which is a pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because `a:hover` is more specific than `a:link`.

If the original `a:hover` font-size was unspecified, it would be inherited from `a:link`. But since there is an `a:hover` specification, `a.myclass:hover` rather takes this value than the more "general" `a.myclass:link`.

I read somewhere to think of the `a` pseudo-classes as "love hate": `:link`, `:visited`, `:hover`, `:active`, one more specific than the previous. If you define something for `a` or `:link`, it should be inherited by all the following pseudo-classes. That value can be overridden though, and the specificity of the pseudo-class is more important than the order in which the styles are defined or what other "real" classes are attached to the link.

The reason it works differently in IE6 is that IE6 does it wrong, which shouldn't come as a surprise.

**Differences in parsing (possibly backwards):**

```
a:hover { font-size: 8pt }
a.myclass:link { font-size: 14px } 
a.myclass:hover { }
```

**How it should be:**

> Every `:hover`, regardless of `.class`, is 8pt.

**How IE6 understands it:**

> `:hover` is not in the same class as `.myclass:hover`. Since there's no size specified for `.myclass:hover`, let's inherit from the next higher available pseudo-class in the same class, which is `.myclass:link`. That makes `.myclass:hover` 14px.

**Estimated lookup priorities:**

```
Others            IE6

a                 a
a.class           a:link
a:link            a:hover
a.class:link      a.class
a:hover           a.class:link
a.class:hover     a.class:hover   <-- Lookup starts here, goes up.
```

Comment: why does this only happen for ie6 then?

Comment: It doesn't "work" in IE6, it's actually borked in IE6. :o) Apparently the IE6 guys prioritized classes over pseudo-classes. While I'm not sure what the official specs says, most everybody else does "pseudo-classes over classes".

Comment: so it should fall back to the a.myclass:link not the a:hover?

Comment: I actually found it works the opposite to that...well either that or something else is interfering.

Comment: Maybe I got it backwards, I was just coasting on your description without testing or looking anything up. You get the idea though. ;)

Comment: hehe...no worries. I think it is th other way around. Will give it a test. Thanks for help though. How do you work around this fact then?

Comment: Try to declare as much as possible in `a` or `a:link`. If you override something in a more specific case, it's safest to explicitly override it in all sub-cases as well. :-/

Answer (score 0):

thats because of the way the styles are being applied
if you would expand the classes you would get:

```
a{ color:red; font-size:10pt;}
a:hover {font-size:8pt; color:black}
a.myclass{font-size:6pt;text-decoration:none;}
a.myclass:hover {color:red}
```

now if we expand this to show whats going on:

```
a.myclass{font-size:6pt;text-decoration:none;**color:red**} /* got the color from a - we overrode the font size */
a.myclass:hover {color:red;text-decoration:none;font-size:8pt} /* we got the text-decoration from a.myclass - but a:hover overrides myclass so we got the 8pt from there */
```

this effect is actually even weirder and more complicated if you start mixing all around effects (border/padding/margin) and side only ones (border-right;margin-top;padding-left) in such constellations.